# Why jquery date dropdowns plugin submit null value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am using: [jQuery Date Dropdowns](http://icklechris.github.io/jquery-date-dropdowns/) plugin.

In my `HTML`:

```
<input type="text" id="dob"/> // plugin will add name="dob" automatically
```

My `JS`:

```
$("#dob").dateDropdowns({
    submitFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    daySuffixes: false,
    submitFieldName: 'dob'
});
```

After submit, output is:

```
"dob" => null
  "dob_" => [
    "day" => "17"
    "month" => "11"
    "year" => "1957"
  ]
```

I also create an [Issue here](https://github.com/IckleChris/jquery-date-dropdowns/issues/27).

Comment: can you reproduce your error here ? [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xwkom9s/)

Comment: Can you show code when you submit?

Comment: I am using [Metronic Admin Template](https://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469)'s [Form Wizard](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/?page=components/forms/wizard/wizard-2&demo=default) so there is too many code.

Comment: So it conflicts with something. Thanks, @Durga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed:**

I am using chrome's [Form Filler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-filler/bnjjngeaknajbdcgpfkgnonkmififhfo) extension to fill input fields for testing. [Form Filler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-filler/bnjjngeaknajbdcgpfkgnonkmififhfo) don't set a value to a hidden field. When I do this manually it works.